# How does this notion compare to that of immersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider a morphism of schemes $f \colon X \to Y$ having the following properties:
i) Topologically, $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.
ii) The induced map of sheaves <strike>$\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_* \mathcal{O}_X$</strike> $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is surjective. (See Wedhorn's answer.)
iii) $f$ is [edit: locally] of finite type. (This excludes morphisms such as $\mathrm{Spec} \; K(X) \to X$ with image the generic point of the variety $X$.)

Clearly, any immersion satisfies these three properties.

> I have two questions:
>   1) Is $f$ necessarily an immersion (i.e., closed immersion followed by an open immersion)?
>   2) If not, are there important properties satisfied by immersions, but not necessarily by morphisms satisfying the three properties above?

Motivation: I find the three properties above more "natural" to work with than the property of being a closed immersion followed by an open immersion.  For instance, it is immediately obvious that the composition of two morphisms satisfying i)-iii) also satisfies i)-iii); I do not find this immediately obvious for immersions in the usual sense (although I will be pleased, if not entirely surprised, if some respondents make this obvious).

Comment: Your condition ii) is rather strange: it is satisfied for closed embedding, obviously, but not for open ones, in general.

Comment: Perhaps (ii) should be replaced with: All stalk maps $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are surjective.

Comment: As for compositions of immersions being immersions, that is easy to see. All you need is to show that any f, which is an open immersion followed by a closed immersion can be factored as a closed immersion followed by an open immersion. The image of your open immersion is an open subset of im f and therefore comes as an intersection of an open set U with im f. Well, in your new factorization U will be give an open immersion and im f \cap U will give a closed immersion (into U).

Comment: It is not true that immersions can always be factorized into an open immersion followed by a closed immersion. A nice example, where this is not possible, can be found in the Stacks project (www.math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git) Example 22.2.10.

Answer (score 5):

As Angelo already pointed out, (ii) is not satisfied by open immersions (e.g. take $R$ a dvr with field of fractions $K$ and let ${\rm Spec} K \to {\rm Spec} R$ be the canonical immersion). In addition not all open immersions are quasi-compact. In particular, they are not necessarily of finite type. Here counterexamples are more difficult to write down as this cannot happen if $Y$ is noetherian.

But nevertheless you were almost there: Immersions $f\colon X \to Y$ can be characterized by the following two properties:

(i) $f$ induces a homeomorphism from $X$ onto a *locally closed* subspace of $Y$.

(ii) $f^{-1}{\mathcal O}_Y \to {\mathcal O}_X$ is surjective.

This is shown in EGA I, (4.2.2).

Comment: If we eliminate the "locally closed" requirement, what utility do we lose in the resulting notion?